# Quitar el focus a un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un anchor link () que es una pregunta. Al clickearlo, en la misma página se visualiza la respuesta sólamente cuando el link se clickea.

```js
function ViewFaqAnswer(answer, question){
FaqHideAll();
$('#' + answer).show();
$('#' + question).css("color","#EB0000");
window.location.hash = answer;


function FaqHideAll() {
$('.faq-answer').hide();
$('.faq-link').css("color","#000099");
}
```

```css
.faq-link{
text-decoration: underline !important;
color: #000099;
}
#faq:focus img, #faq:hover img{
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(38, 143, 255,1)
}
```

```html
 <table role="presentation">
  <tr>
  <td>
<a href="javascript: ViewFaqAnswer('answer','question')" class="faq-link"> Question </a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>



<table role="presentation" class="faq-answer" style="display: none; width: 100% border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" tabindex="0">
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> Title </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
  <p> Answer </p>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

El tema es que al hacer click se hace el focus en la respuesta y lo que quiero es que sólamente se visualice y el usuario navegue hasta la pregunta.

Esto debería ser aplicado con javascript? O con css podría hacerse?

Comment: Sebastián, bienvenido. Las preguntas requieren un mínimo de código para ser revisadas y así tratar de ayudarte. Sin código no podemos ofrecerte respuestas claras ya que estaríamos adivinando lo que tienes y es posible que no sea lo que necesitas. Haz el recorrido que está en el footer del sitio para que comprendas lo que te comento.

Comment: Bienvenido Sebastián. Entonces, ¿Deseas saber como quitar el foco a un elemento HTML o saber si es aconsejable emplear CSS en lugar de JS para ello?

Comment: Si, quisiera saber cómo quitar el foco. Lo que intenté es en la función ViewFaqAnswer traté de agregar $('#' + answer).blur(); Tal vez estoy haciendo mal uso de la misma. Y si, también me gustaría saber qué es recomendable usar, si CSS o JS. Desde ya muchas gracias, y gracias por la bienvenida.

Comment: No se si te refieres a usar el atributo `tabindex="-1"` en el elemento con id #+answer (que por cierto no sale en tu ejemplo de código) o bien a cambiar el `window.location.hash = answer;` por `window.location.hash = question;`.  Sea como sea tu ejemplo no nos sirve para comprobarlo pues tiene errores de sintaxis. Léete [ask], [tour] y sobretodo [example] para aprender bien el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: Al final lo resolví con esto:function ViewFaqAnswer(answer, question) {
    FaqHideAll();
    //Bug 95790
    $('#' + answer).show();
    $('#' + question).focus();
    $('#' + question).css("color", "#EB0000");
    window.location.hash = question;
}

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví agregando .focus();

```
  function ViewFaqAnswer(answer, question) {
    FaqHideAll();
    $('#' + answer).show();
    $('#' + question).focus();
    $('#' + question).css("color", "#EB0000");
    window.location.hash = question;
}
```

Gracias masterguru por tu clarificación.